# Mongoose findOne() is not giving desired output

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm making a full-stack website where I need login system I'm connecting my project with mongodb using mongoose when the user register his data inserted successfully in the database the problem is when logging in when I try to find an email which is already registered it always respond with user not found.

I'm trying to check if the user is registered so I can make him able to log in but it always respond with null even if he is registered.

This is when I try to login but always respond with user not found:

**Router code:**

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

// the problem is here in the findOne function 

 User.findOne({ email:email }).then(user => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ email: "User not found" });
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (isMatch) {
        res.json({ msg: "Success" });
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ password: "password incorrect" });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Schema code:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Comment: if you remove `bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)` part, and `return user` on success, would it work correctly in your case? Does `user` found itself by `email` field, is he exists?

Comment: thanks for answering but no because he can't just log in with email the problem with the code is even when the email is found it does not got to the next step to check if the password is correct

Comment: user is checked to be found or not by his email so if he is not found it says user is not found but if he is found then he checks if the password is correct if it is incorrect then it says password is incorrect

Comment: I understood the logic of you code, I said if you remove `bcryct` check by hash-password, does `findOne` method finds user correctly by email? Just reply to me: "Y or N". And try to use commas when you'll make your next comment.

Comment: no, it gives me the same "user is not found"

Comment: you'll find this question relevant to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57841490/how-to-check-if-selected-email-name-is-alread-exist-in-mongodb

Comment: it still not working the find method still return nothing

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. I took your code, repurposed it as shown in the example below. It works as is.

Setup your Model like this (in a file of its own if you will):

```
// Your mongoose model
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password_hash: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema, 'users');
```

Setup your route handler like this (in a file of it's own if you will). Import the User model and bcrypt as follows. Notice I added a /register route. This is to show you how you can handle registration, and store password.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../model/so.user.model');

// Note: Login route for demo purposes
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log({email, password});
    // Note: Basic validity check for demo purposes
    if (!email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'No data provided' });
    } else {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
        }
        try {
            isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password_hash);
            if (isMatch) {
                res.status(200).json({ message: `Login successful for ${user.name}` });
                /* ==== Response sent to client =====
                    {
                        "message": "Login successful for Grey"
                    } 
                */
            } else {
                return res.status(400).json({ password: 'password incorrect' });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({ error, message: 'Something went wrong' });
        }
    }

});

// Note: Registration route for demo purposes
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    const saltRounds = 4;

    // Note: Basic validity check for demo purposes
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'No data provided' });
    } else {
        try {
            const password_hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
            const newUser = User({
                name,
                email,
                password_hash
            });
            savedUser = await newUser.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'User created successfully',
                data: savedUser
            });

            /* ====== Response sent to client =============
                {
                    "message": "User created successfully",
                    "data": {
                    "__v": 0,
                    "name": "Grey",
                    "email": "grey@asheori.com",
                    "password_hash": "$2b$04$Lu5FeGmSLzuVv2pctO7pQOBbK/wnETr6TqaWXcshUwpcjPA3fXo/G",
                    "_id": "5d75ab74f5f93903fb2d3305",
                    "date": "2019-09-09T01:31:32.235Z"
                    }
                } 
            */

        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong' });
        }
    }
});
```