# How to check if selected email & name is alread exist in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to get information if selected user email & name already exist somewhere in MongoDB database. I want to make email and name unique, therefore it couldn't be duplicates of both those values.

I already wrote working code, but I would like to know if this solution is optimal.

```
User.find({ email: email })
        .then(user => {
            if (user.length >= 1) {
                return res.status(409).json({
                    message: 'Mail exists'
                })
            } else {
                User.find({ name: name })
                    .then(user => {
                        if (user.length >= 1) {
                            return res.status(409).json({
                                message: 'Name exist'
                            })
                        } else {

                         // SOME CODE HERE

                        }
                    })
            }
        })
```

Is there any shorter way to write this? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want both email+name to be unique or email unique and name unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1** - You need the pair to be unique

In this case the pair (email,name) will be unique. This can be done using **AND** query.

```
User.find({email:email,name:name})
```

**Case 2** - You do not need either email or name appear twice

This can cause some issues since there can be two people with same name but different email. This condition can be met using **OR** querying.

```
User.find({$or:[{email:email},{name:name}]}
```

*Personal recommendation : Follow the solution given by @will-alexander It will be more efficient.*

Comment: It's worth noting that both this solution and the mongoose-unique-validator solution rely on asynchronous database calls, so still would allow for the possibility of inserting 2 documents with the same fields. For cases like this, I'd argue it's best to rely on mongo to do the enforcement by creating a unique index. If you do go down this route, just make sure you're throttling your client-side form submissions so that double-clicks can't create 2 users

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongoose, you can achieve this from within the Model using `mongoose-unique-validator`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This way, if Mongoose detects you trying to add a User with an existing name or email, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want uniqueness on both the keys use in one query

`User.find({email:email,name:name})`

If you want both keys to be separately unique use in one query

`User.find({$or:[{email:email},{name:name}]}`